# In VB6 what is the default type for a variable?

Tags: vb6

If one declares a VB6 variable thus...

```
Public THISVAR, THATVAR, THEOTHERVAR
```

what type are the variables created?

Comment: D'oh! Of course! Thanks for your help, chaps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variant -> see [Variant Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type)

Comment: **Nearly** always true. If the original programmer really wanted to confuse you, the Def*Type* statements can change the defaults module-by-module and by the initial letter of the variable name. VB6 manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263421(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 2):

They'll be [Variants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/696fhwxz%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) - able to contain anything.

Comment: The link to MSDN page isn't working any more

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Usually these end up being Variants but you can use DefXxx statements to alter default data types based on first letter of a variable name which is kind of weird legacy feature.

We use `DefObj A-Z` in all our modules immediately after `Option Explicit` so that typeless vars, params and retvals (not allowed here by coding conventions) end up being `As Object` and usually generate compile-time errors or crash in flames at run-time.

So in your case these would be `Nothing` (uninitialized `As Object` var) if this declaration happen to be one of our modules.

Answer (score 1):

complete datatype description in vb; the default type is **Variant Types**

```
Data type ____________________ Storage size



Byte-------------------------------1 byte   
Boolean----------------------------2 bytes  
Integer----------------------------2 bytes  
Long
(long integer)---------------------4 bytes  
Single-----------------------------4 bytes  
(single-precision floating-point)   
Double-----------------------------8 bytes
(double-precision floating-point)       
Currency
(scaled integer)-------------------8 bytes
Decimal---------------------------14 bytes  
Date------------------------------ 8 bytes  
Object-----------------------------4 bytes  
String 
(variable-length)-----------------10 bytes 
Variant
(with numbers)--------------------16 bytes  
Variant
(with characters)-----------------22 bytes + string length
User-defined
```